# Getting graphic card information in objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to get Graphics card information in my application. The information I need is the same as displayed by ***system_profiler SPDisplays*** command under the section *Graphics/Displays:*.
I have already considered using ***sysctl()***, but I am unable to find proper hardware selector for graphics card in sysctl.h

Any suggestions highly appericiated.

Comment: You should use IOKit instead of sysctl: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Macmade . I shall start with IOKit straightaway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After fiddling with IOKit I have managed to fetch the required information. The code can be seen [here](http://goo.gl/kvLCjg) ([original source](http://www.starcoder.com/wordpress/2011/10/using-iokit-to-detect-graphics-hardware/))and below:

```
- (void)displayGraphicsInfo
{
    // Get dictionary of all the PCI Devicces
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = IOServiceMatching("IOPCIDevice");

    // Create an iterator
    io_iterator_t iterator;

    if (IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,matchDict,
                                     &iterator) == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        // Iterator for devices found
        io_registry_entry_t regEntry;

        while ((regEntry = IOIteratorNext(iterator))) {
            // Put this services object into a dictionary object.
            CFMutableDictionaryRef serviceDictionary;
            if (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(regEntry,
                                                  &serviceDictionary,
                                                  kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                  kNilOptions) != kIOReturnSuccess)
            {
                // Service dictionary creation failed.
                IOObjectRelease(regEntry);
                continue;
            }
            const void *GPUModel = CFDictionaryGetValue(serviceDictionary, @"model");

            if (GPUModel != nil) {
                if (CFGetTypeID(GPUModel) == CFDataGetTypeID()) {
                    // Create a string from the CFDataRef.
                    NSString *modelName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                                           (NSData *)GPUModel encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    NSLog(@"GPU Model: %@", modelName);
                    [modelName release];
                }
            }
            // Release the dictionary
            CFRelease(serviceDictionary);
            // Release the serviceObject
            IOObjectRelease(regEntry);
        }
        // Release the iterator
        IOObjectRelease(iterator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code from your website, which at present is currently down. (See also [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)).

Comment: Hello @rsharma! I have  submitted an edition to your answer to include the code from that link so that your answer remains valid even if the site is shutdown by the owner.

Comment: Yeah this code looks like it's from [here](http://www.starcoder.com/wordpress/2011/10/using-iokit-to-detect-graphics-hardware/) without attribution.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes may be. It's an old post I created and I might have missed to refer to the source. I'll do it straight away (and also on the answer).