# GPU info through Metal framenwork's registryID instance property

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal, macos-high-sierra

I'm searching for GPU information through the IO matching "IOPCIDevice" and should be nice to have info about Metal, i.e if is supported or not (I still support some years old MacPro). I see that Metal 2 has a new property called [registryID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/2915737-registryid) and I've tried to match the IOIteratorNext, but it didn't. The code I use is just the same described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077639/getting-graphic-card-information-in-objective-c?answertab=active#tab-top) by @rsharma (credits goes to @trojanfoe) with little modifications. 
So my question is: how can I use registryID to ensure is the same graphics card?

P.S. I already have an array of i/GPU that support Metal using MTLCopyAllDevices.

Comment: What's an example value of `registryID` that you've seen? Have you used IORegistryExplorer.app to see if any of the properties of the devices correspond to that value? It may not correspond to any property in the IO registry. It may have been invented by, say, the WindowServer process. The only thing documented about it is that it's the same across all tasks (which I assume means processes in a session). I assume its purpose is to allow multiple tasks to coordinate which GPU they're working with.

Comment: Hi, I didn't see any example, just initialize MTLCopyAllDevices which return an array of gpu that support Metal. From now on is easy to get for each one of it its registryID that is a 64 bit integer as expected as any other entry in the IO registry. What I found (look at @rsharma's code) that I have only the IOIteratorNext to rely on. I was wondering if Metal's registryID is somehow reachable from the mentioned code to have a match. By printing both integers is clear that they are entries not too far from each other like parent and children. I'll post an example as soon as I'll be at Home. thx

Comment: If it's a real registry entry ID, then you can use `IORegistryEntryIDMatching()` instead of `IOServiceMatching()`. For each match (there would presumably be only one), you'd probably want to dump its properties, class, path, etc. rather than assuming it's a GPU entry.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm happy to accept your comment as an answer if you make so!

Answer (score 2):

Given a registry entry ID, you can use `IORegistryEntryIDMatching()` to create a matching dictionary. You would then pass that to `IOServiceGetMatchingService()` (on the assumption that there's only one) or `IOServiceGetMatchingServices()` to retrieve the object.

Comment: Thanks, as I already said in my comment, that worked. To be 101% sure I'm comparing also the device id from the previous dictionary (@rsharma's code) with the new one: perfect!